# Android prevent keyboard from closing

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard, user-input

Is it possible to prevent the user from closing the soft keyboard. In other words, keyboard to be available on the screen (at all times) while my activity is visible. Is this possible? If so, how would you accomplish it?

Comment: Added android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" to the activity definition in AndroidManifest.xml. Also tried various combinations using the InputMethodManager, none worked.

Answer (score 1):

This should force the keyboard to show regardless of focus :

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourViewObject.getWindowToken(), 0);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to override the `onKeyUp()` and `onKeyDown()` methods like below,

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)     
    {
        ((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).toggleSoftInput
                (InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)     
    {
        ((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).toggleSoftInput
                (InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

You can also try in either way, by using `OnEditorActionListener`, have a look at following code,

```
EditText txtMyEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEdit);
txtMyEdit.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() 
{
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) 
        {
            // your additional processing... 
            return true;
        } 
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This works somewhat, the only issue is that a change in focus still causes the keyboard to be dismissed. I need the keyboard to remain on the screen at all times.