# Android: Prevent soft keyboard from closing in a chat window

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext, chat, android-softkeyboard

I'm making a chat app and would like to keep the soft keyboard open while the chat window is visible. The keyboard should not hide when the user taps any other control on the same page. My view hierarchy looks like this:

```
LinearLayout
   RecyclerView
   LinearLayout
```

The child linear layout has an `EditText` and a button to send a message. Once the page is shown, I'm requesting focus on the edit text and showing soft input with the `SHOW_FORCED` flag. The problem is when I tap on the `RecyclerView` or the send button and if the edit text has focus, then the keyboard will hide.

Is it possible to make sure the edit text never loses focus (thus preventing the keyboard from disappearing)? I was able to accomplish this with ease on iOS, but I'm having difficulty with Android.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android prevent keyboard from closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022460/android-prevent-keyboard-from-closing)

Comment: No, it doesn't. As I mentioned in my answer, I have a custom button to send a message. I'm not sending messages through the Done button of the keyboard. The user has to manually tap the button to send a message. `SHOW_FORCED` is not working for me.

Comment: could you confirm if this behavior is reproducible on emulators?

Comment: Can you please share XML code of EditiText, Button and that <activity> from your manifest file?

Comment: In the given scenario keyboard stays open for me by default. So can you please share your layout & also what you're doing on send button click?

Comment: @user246392 are you using send action from the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the focus of **editText** not to lose use this,it worked for me

```
    edit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(!edit.hasFocus()){
        edit.requestFocus();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't need just the focus. I need the soft keyboard to never disappear while the chat window is open. Right now, when I click a button to send a message, the keyboard disappears. I have to tap the EditText again to show the keyboard.

Comment: can you share your code that i can help you better

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind I have not tried building this, since is complex. I'll try adding an example, if I get the time.

I guess you want to build something akin to whatsapp. The most promising way, in my opinion, is to set up a global touchListener in your root linearLayout, which consumes all touch events while making the children unfocusable, therefore allowing you to manually handle all the touch events. If you detect a sliding touch, scroll the recyclerview accordingly. If you detect a touch in the edittext area, set the focus & open the keyboard. That way the touches  won't change the focus state, keeping the keyboard open. Keep in mind you'll probable have to handle all the other touch scenarios. Start by creating the listener & make everything but the first layout not focusable on touch, and then build your specific interactions.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is that when the EditText loses focus, focus it again and show the keyboard. But this is just the workaround. If you can share what you have done so far it would be easy.

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener( new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v,boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!editText.hasFocus()) {
            editText.requestFocus();
            editText.postDelayed(() -> showSoftKeyboard(editText.getContext(),editText),100);
        }
    }
});

public static void showSoftKeyboard(Context context, View view) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (inputMethodManager != null) {
        inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
}
```

The delay is because sometimes focus keyboard doesnt show up.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. What happens with this implementation is that the keyboard closes when edit text loses focus when I click the send button and it appears again. I don't want the keyboard to close at all.